# HDF5 dataloading very slow. Causes zero % volatility in GPUs

Tags: python, linux, pytorch, gpu, hdf5

I am using a custom PyTorch dataclass to load instances from a H5 dataset I created. However, it appears to be incredibly slow when loading samples. I have followed several bits of advice on dealing with large HDF5 datasets, but I am wondering whether I am doing something that is obviously wrong. I am deploying my code on Linux if that makes a difference. I am running the code on 4 GPUs with nn.dataparallel in place for my model. As the dataloading is very slow, the GPU Volatility is at 0%.  Here is my dataclass loader:

```
import h5py
from torch.utils import data

class Features_Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, archive, phase):
        self.archive = archive
        self.phase = phase

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        with h5py.File(self.archive, 'r', libver='latest', swmr=True) as archive:
            datum = archive[str(self.phase) + '_all_arrays'][index]
            label = archive[str(self.phase) + '_labels'][index]
            path = archive[str(self.phase) +  '_img_paths'][index]
            return datum, label, path

    def __len__(self):
        with h5py.File(self.archive, 'r', libver='latest', swmr=True) as archive:
            datum = archive[str(self.phase) + '_all_arrays']
            return len(datum)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dataset = Features_Dataset(archive= "featuresdata/train.hdf5", phase= 'train')
    trainloader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, num_workers=8, batch_size=128)
    print(len(trainloader))
    for i, (data, label, path) in enumerate(trainloader):
        print(path)
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better way of loading instances rapidly?

EDIT:

Here is the updated dataclass however I now get a picling error when trying to use multiprocessing.

```
import h5py
from torch.utils import data
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('spawn')

class Features_Dataset(data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, archive, phase):
        self.archive = h5py.File(archive, 'r')
        self.labels = self.archive[str(phase) + '_labels']
        self.data = self.archive[str(phase) + '_all_arrays']
        self.img_paths = self.archive[str(phase) + '_img_paths']

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        datum = self.data[index]
        label = self.labels[index]
        path = self.img_paths[index]
        return datum, label, path

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def close(self):
        self.archive.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dataset = Features_Dataset(archive= "featuresdata/train.hdf5", phase= 'train')
    trainloader = data.DataLoader(train_dataset, num_workers=2, batch_size=4)
    print(len(trainloader))
    for i, (data, label, path) in enumerate(trainloader):
        print(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not open file once in the init and store the file handler? Currently when ever you called get item or len, you will be always opening the file on each call.

Comment: Hi, So I have tried opening it in the __init__. When I try to use more than 1 worker, I end up with an error. I was told that I should use `import torch.multiprocessing as mp
mp.set_start_method('spawn')`. However, I get a pickling error: TypeError: h5py objects cannot be pickled. I've added the new class to my original post.

Comment: Have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684061/typeerror-h5py-objects-cannot-be-pickled

Comment: Hi, Yes, So I've had a go at placing `[()]` for the arrays in __init__:  `self.labels = self.archive[str(phase) + '_labels'][()]` . This works on tiny datasets, however I'm assuming I run into a memory error when I use a large dataset: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (2140063, 1, 6144, 1, 1) and data type float32`. When I place `[()]` in __getitem__, which I assume is the proper place, for example, `datum = self.data[index][()]`, I will get an error for labels and paths; `TypeError: string indices must be integers` . Is there a viable workaround?

Comment: Also, with just the data placed into numpy arrays example, I still get `TypeError: h5py objects cannot be pickled`

Comment: I hope you resolve it. Just an idea is to read the h5 in a separate process and add the data into a multiprocessing queue. The 4 gpu processes consumes the data from the queue. Essentially creating your own dataloader instead of using the pytorch data loader. I have only created the data loading part recently for pytorch inference and manage to increase the throughput of the system.

Comment: Have solved this? I'm having the exact same issue.