# Python ERROR => h5py objects cannot be pickled

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, hdf5

Can any one help me

### I am facing this error "h5py objects cannot be pickled" while running (train.py) on https://github.com/RoyalSkye/Image-Caption
(my OS is Window 10)

train.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import h5py
import time
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch import nn
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence
from models import *
from transformer import *
from datasets import *
from utils import *
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu
import argparse
import codecs
import numpy as np


def train(args, train_loader, encoder, decoder, criterion, encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer, epoch):
    """
    Performs one epoch's training.

    :param train_loader: DataLoader for training data
    :param encoder: encoder model
    :param decoder: decoder model
    :param criterion: loss layer
    :param encoder_optimizer: optimizer to update encoder's weights (if fine-tuning)
    :param decoder_optimizer: optimizer to update decoder's weights
    :param epoch: epoch number
    """

    decoder.train()  # train mode (dropout and batchnorm is used)
    encoder.train()

    batch_time = AverageMeter()  # forward prop. + back prop. time
    data_time = AverageMeter()  # data loading time
    losses = AverageMeter()  # loss (per word decoded)
    top5accs = AverageMeter()  # top5 accuracy

    start = time.time()

    # Batches
    for i, (imgs, caps, caplens) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data_time.update(time.time() - start)

        # Move to GPU, if available
        imgs = imgs.to(device)
        caps = caps.to(device)
        caplens = caplens.to(device)

        # Forward prop.
        imgs = encoder(imgs)
        # imgs: [batch_size, 14, 14, 2048]
        # caps: [batch_size, 52]
        # caplens: [batch_size, 1]
        scores, caps_sorted, decode_lengths, alphas, sort_ind = decoder(imgs, caps, caplens)

        # Since we decoded starting with <start>, the targets are all words after <start>, up to <end>
        targets = caps_sorted[:, 1:]

        # Remove timesteps that we didn't decode at, or are pads
        # pack_padded_sequence is an easy trick to do this
        scores = pack_padded_sequence(scores, decode_lengths, batch_first=True).data
        targets = pack_padded_sequence(targets, decode_lengths, batch_first=True).data
        # print(scores.size())
        # print(targets.size())

        # Calculate loss
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)
        # Add doubly stochastic attention regularization
        # Second loss, mentioned in paper "Show, Attend and Tell: Neural Image Caption Generation with Visual Attention"
        # https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03044
        # In section 4.2.1 Doubly stochastic attention regularization: We know the weights sum to 1 at a given timestep.
        # But we also encourage the weights at a single pixel p to sum to 1 across all timesteps T.
        # This means we want the model to attend to every pixel over the course of generating the entire sequence.
        # Therefore, we want to minimize the difference between 1 and the sum of a pixel's weights across all timesteps.
        if args.decoder_mode == "lstm":
            loss += args.alpha_c * ((1. - alphas.sum(dim=1)) ** 2).mean()
        elif args.decoder_mode == "transformer":
            dec_alphas = alphas["dec_enc_attns"]
            alpha_trans_c = args.alpha_c / (args.n_heads * args.decoder_layers)
            for layer in range(args.decoder_layers):  # args.decoder_layers = len(dec_alphas)
                cur_layer_alphas = dec_alphas[layer]  # [batch_size, n_heads, 52, 196]
                for h in range(args.n_heads):
                    cur_head_alpha = cur_layer_alphas[:, h, :, :]
                    loss += alpha_trans_c * ((1. - cur_head_alpha.sum(dim=1)) ** 2).mean()

        # Back prop.
        decoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
        if encoder_optimizer is not None:
            encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # Clip gradients
        if args.grad_clip is not None:
            clip_gradient(decoder_optimizer, args.grad_clip)
            if encoder_optimizer is not None:
                clip_gradient(encoder_optimizer, args.grad_clip)

        # Update weights
        decoder_optimizer.step()
        if encoder_optimizer is not None:
            encoder_optimizer.step()

        # Keep track of metrics
        top5 = accuracy(scores, targets, 5)
        losses.update(loss.item(), sum(decode_lengths))
        top5accs.update(top5, sum(decode_lengths))
        batch_time.update(time.time() - start)
        start = time.time()
        if i % args.print_freq == 0:
            print("Epoch: {}/{} step: {}/{} Loss: {} AVG_Loss: {} Top-5 Accuracy: {} Batch_time: {}s".format(epoch+1, args.epochs, i+1, len(train_loader), losses.val, losses.avg, top5accs.val, batch_time.val))


def validate(args, val_loader, encoder, decoder, criterion):
    """
    Performs one epoch's validation.

    :param val_loader: DataLoader for validation data.
    :param encoder: encoder model
    :param decoder: decoder model
    :param criterion: loss layer
    :return: score_dict {'Bleu_1': 0., 'Bleu_2': 0., 'Bleu_3': 0., 'Bleu_4': 0., 'METEOR': 0., 'ROUGE_L': 0., 'CIDEr': 1.}
    """
    decoder.eval()  # eval mode (no dropout or batchnorm)
    if encoder is not None:
        encoder.eval()

    batch_time = AverageMeter()
    losses = AverageMeter()
    top5accs = AverageMeter()

    start = time.time()

    references = list()  # references (true captions) for calculating BLEU-4 score
    hypotheses = list()  # hypotheses (predictions)

    # explicitly disable gradient calculation to avoid CUDA memory error
    with torch.no_grad():
        # Batches
        for i, (imgs, caps, caplens, allcaps) in enumerate(val_loader):

            # Move to device, if available
            imgs = imgs.to(device)
            caps = caps.to(device)
            caplens = caplens.to(device)

            # Forward prop.
            if encoder is not None:
                imgs = encoder(imgs)
            scores, caps_sorted, decode_lengths, alphas, sort_ind = decoder(imgs, caps, caplens)

            # Since we decoded starting with <start>, the targets are all words after <start>, up to <end>
            targets = caps_sorted[:, 1:]

            # Remove timesteps that we didn't decode at, or are pads
            # pack_padded_sequence is an easy trick to do this
            scores_copy = scores.clone()
            scores = pack_padded_sequence(scores, decode_lengths, batch_first=True).data
            targets = pack_padded_sequence(targets, decode_lengths, batch_first=True).data

            # Calculate loss
            loss = criterion(scores, targets)

            # Add doubly stochastic attention regularization
            if args.decoder_mode == "lstm":
                loss += args.alpha_c * ((1. - alphas.sum(dim=1)) ** 2).mean()
            elif args.decoder_mode == "transformer":
                dec_alphas = alphas["dec_enc_attns"]
                alpha_trans_c = args.alpha_c / (args.n_heads * args.decoder_layers)
                for layer in range(args.decoder_layers):  # args.decoder_layers = len(dec_alphas)
                    cur_layer_alphas = dec_alphas[layer]  # [batch_size, n_heads, 52, 196]
                    for h in range(args.n_heads):
                        cur_head_alpha = cur_layer_alphas[:, h, :, :]
                        loss += alpha_trans_c * ((1. - cur_head_alpha.sum(dim=1)) ** 2).mean()

            # Keep track of metrics
            losses.update(loss.item(), sum(decode_lengths))
            top5 = accuracy(scores, targets, 5)
            top5accs.update(top5, sum(decode_lengths))
            batch_time.update(time.time() - start)
            start = time.time()

            # Store references (true captions), and hypothesis (prediction) for each image
            # If for n images, we have n hypotheses, and references a, b, c... for each image, we need -
            # references = [[ref1a, ref1b, ref1c], [ref2a, ref2b], ...], hypotheses = [hyp1, hyp2, ...]

            # References
            allcaps = allcaps[sort_ind]  # because images were sorted in the decoder
            for j in range(allcaps.shape[0]):
                img_caps = allcaps[j].tolist()
                img_captions = list(
                    map(lambda c: [w for w in c if w not in {word_map['<start>'], word_map['<pad>']}],
                        img_caps))  # remove <start> and pads
                references.append(img_captions)

            # Hypotheses
            _, preds = torch.max(scores_copy, dim=2)
            preds = preds.tolist()
            temp_preds = list()
            for j, p in enumerate(preds):
                temp_preds.append(preds[j][:decode_lengths[j]])  # remove pads
            preds = temp_preds
            hypotheses.extend(preds)

            assert len(references) == len(hypotheses)

    # Calculate BLEU-1~4 scores
    # metrics = {}
    # weights = (1.0 / 1.0,)
    # metrics["bleu1"] = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights)
    # weights = (1.0/2.0, 1.0/2.0,)
    # metrics["bleu2"] = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights)
    # weights = (1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0,)
    # metrics["bleu3"] = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses, weights)
    # metrics["bleu4"] = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses)

    # Calculate BLEU1~4, METEOR, ROUGE_L, CIDEr scores
    metrics = get_eval_score(references, hypotheses)

    print("EVA LOSS: {} TOP-5 Accuracy {} BLEU-1 {} BLEU2 {} BLEU3 {} BLEU-4 {} METEOR {} ROUGE_L {} CIDEr {}".format
          (losses.avg, top5accs.avg,  metrics["Bleu_1"],  metrics["Bleu_2"],  metrics["Bleu_3"],  metrics["Bleu_4"],
           metrics["METEOR"], metrics["ROUGE_L"], metrics["CIDEr"]))

    return metrics


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Image_Captioning')
    # Data parameters
    parser.add_argument('--data_folder', default="./dataset/generated_data",
                        help='folder with data files saved by create_input_files.py.')
    parser.add_argument('--data_name', default="coco_5_cap_per_img_5_min_word_freq",
                        help='base name shared by data files.')
    # Model parameters
    parser.add_argument('--emb_dim', type=int, default=300, help='dimension of word embeddings.')
    parser.add_argument('--attention_dim', type=int, default=512, help='dimension of attention linear layers.')
    parser.add_argument('--decoder_dim', type=int, default=512, help='dimension of decoder RNN.')
    parser.add_argument('--n_heads', type=int, default=8, help='Multi-head attention.')
    parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.1, help='dropout')
    parser.add_argument('--decoder_mode', default="transformer", help='which model does decoder use?')  # lstm or transformer
    parser.add_argument('--attention_method', default="ByPixel", help='which attention method to use?')  # ByPixel or ByChannel
    parser.add_argument('--encoder_layers', type=int, default=2, help='the number of layers of encoder in Transformer.')
    parser.add_argument('--decoder_layers', type=int, default=6, help='the number of layers of decoder in Transformer.')
    # Training parameters
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=100,
                        help='number of epochs to train for (if early stopping is not triggered).')
    parser.add_argument('--stop_criteria', type=int, default=25, help='training stop if epochs_since_improvement == stop_criteria')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=32, help='batch_size')
    parser.add_argument('--print_freq', type=int, default=100, help='print training/validation stats every __ batches.')
    parser.add_argument('--workers', type=int, default=1, help='for data-loading; right now, only 1 works with h5pys.')
    parser.add_argument('--encoder_lr', type=float, default=1e-4, help='learning rate for encoder if fine-tuning.')
    parser.add_argument('--decoder_lr', type=float, default=1e-4, help='learning rate for decoder.')
    parser.add_argument('--grad_clip', type=float, default=5., help='clip gradients at an absolute value of.')
    parser.add_argument('--alpha_c', type=float, default=1.,
                        help='regularization parameter for doubly stochastic attention, as in the paper.')
    parser.add_argument('--fine_tune_encoder', type=bool, default=False, help='whether fine-tune encoder or not')
    parser.add_argument('--fine_tune_embedding', type=bool, default=False, help='whether fine-tune word embeddings or not')
    parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', default=None, help='path to checkpoint, None if none.')
    parser.add_argument('--embedding_path', default=None, help='path to pre-trained word Embedding.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # load checkpoint, these parameters can't be modified
    final_args = {"emb_dim": args.emb_dim,
                 "attention_dim": args.attention_dim,
                 "decoder_dim": args.decoder_dim,
                 "n_heads": args.n_heads,
                 "dropout": args.dropout,
                 "decoder_mode": args.decoder_mode,
                 "attention_method": args.attention_method,
                 "encoder_layers": args.encoder_layers,
                 "decoder_layers": args.decoder_layers}

    start_epoch = 0
    best_bleu4 = 0.  # BLEU-4 score right now
    epochs_since_improvement = 0  # keeps track of number of epochs since there's been an improvement in validation BLEU
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")  # sets device for model and PyTorch tensors
    cudnn.benchmark = True  # set to true only if inputs to model are fixed size; otherwise lot of computational overhead
    print(device)

    # Read word map
    word_map_file = os.path.join(args.data_folder, 'WORDMAP_' + args.data_name + '.json')
    with open(word_map_file, 'r') as j:
        word_map = json.load(j)

    # Initialize / load checkpoint
    if args.checkpoint is None:
        encoder = CNN_Encoder(attention_method=args.attention_method)
        encoder.fine_tune(args.fine_tune_encoder)
        encoder_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, encoder.parameters()),
                                             lr=args.encoder_lr) if args.fine_tune_encoder else None

        if args.decoder_mode == "lstm":
            decoder = DecoderWithAttention(attention_dim=args.attention_dim,
                                           embed_dim=args.emb_dim,
                                           decoder_dim=args.decoder_dim,
                                           vocab_size=len(word_map),
                                           dropout=args.dropout)
        elif args.decoder_mode == "transformer":
            decoder = Transformer(vocab_size=len(word_map), embed_dim=args.emb_dim, encoder_layers=args.encoder_layers,
                                  decoder_layers=args.decoder_layers, dropout=args.dropout,
                                  attention_method=args.attention_method, n_heads=args.n_heads)

        decoder_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, decoder.parameters()),
                                             lr=args.decoder_lr)

        # load pre-trained word embedding
        if args.embedding_path is not None:
            all_word_embeds = {}
            for i, line in enumerate(codecs.open(args.embedding_path, 'r', 'utf-8')):
                s = line.strip().split()
                all_word_embeds[s[0]] = np.array([float(i) for i in s[1:]])

            # change emb_dim
            args.emb_dim = list(all_word_embeds.values())[-1].size
            word_embeds = np.random.uniform(-np.sqrt(0.06), np.sqrt(0.06), (len(word_map), args.emb_dim))
            for w in word_map:
                if w in all_word_embeds:
                    word_embeds[word_map[w]] = all_word_embeds[w]
                elif w.lower() in all_word_embeds:
                    word_embeds[word_map[w]] = all_word_embeds[w.lower()]
                else:
                    # <pad> <start> <end> <unk>
                    embedding_i = torch.ones(1, args.emb_dim)
                    torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(embedding_i)
                    word_embeds[word_map[w]] = embedding_i

            word_embeds = torch.FloatTensor(word_embeds).to(device)
            decoder.load_pretrained_embeddings(word_embeds)
            decoder.fine_tune_embeddings(args.fine_tune_embedding)
            print('Loaded {} pre-trained word embeddings.'.format(len(word_embeds)))

    else:
        checkpoint = torch.load(args.checkpoint, map_location=str(device))
        start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch'] + 1
        epochs_since_improvement = checkpoint['epochs_since_improvement']
        best_bleu4 = checkpoint['metrics']["Bleu_4"]
        encoder = checkpoint['encoder']
        encoder_optimizer = checkpoint['encoder_optimizer']
        decoder = checkpoint['decoder']
        decoder_optimizer = checkpoint['decoder_optimizer']
        decoder.fine_tune_embeddings(args.fine_tune_embedding)
        # load final_args from checkpoint
        final_args = checkpoint['final_args']
        for key in final_args.keys():
            args.__setattr__(key, final_args[key])
        if args.fine_tune_encoder is True and encoder_optimizer is None:
            print("Encoder_Optimizer is None, Creating new Encoder_Optimizer!")
            encoder.fine_tune(args.fine_tune_encoder)
            encoder_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, encoder.parameters()),
                                                 lr=args.encoder_lr)

    # Move to GPU, if available
    decoder = decoder.to(device)
    encoder = encoder.to(device)
    print("encoder_layers {} decoder_layers {} n_heads {} dropout {} attention_method {} encoder_lr {} "
          "decoder_lr {} alpha_c {}".format(args.encoder_layers, args.decoder_layers, args.n_heads, args.dropout,
                                            args.attention_method, args.encoder_lr, args.decoder_lr, args.alpha_c))
    print(encoder)
    print(decoder)

    # Loss function
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

    # Custom dataloaders
    normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    # normalize = transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

    # pin_memory: If True, the data loader will copy Tensors into CUDA pinned memory before returning them.
    # If your data elements are a custom type, or your collate_fn returns a batch that is a custom type.
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        CaptionDataset(args.data_folder, args.data_name, 'TRAIN', transform=transforms.Compose([normalize])),
        batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=args.workers, pin_memory=True)
    val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        CaptionDataset(args.data_folder, args.data_name, 'VAL', transform=transforms.Compose([normalize])),
        batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=args.workers, pin_memory=True)

    # Epochs
    for epoch in range(start_epoch, args.epochs):

        # Decay learning rate if there is no improvement for 5 consecutive epochs, and terminate training after 25
        # 8 20
        if epochs_since_improvement == args.stop_criteria:
            print("the model has not improved in the last {} epochs".format(args.stop_criteria))
            break
        if epochs_since_improvement > 0 and epochs_since_improvement % 5 == 0:
            adjust_learning_rate(decoder_optimizer, 0.8)
            if args.fine_tune_encoder and encoder_optimizer is not None:
                print(encoder_optimizer)
                adjust_learning_rate(encoder_optimizer, 0.8)

        # One epoch's training
        train(args, train_loader=train_loader, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, criterion=criterion,
              encoder_optimizer=encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer=decoder_optimizer, epoch=epoch)

        # One epoch's validation
        metrics = validate(args, val_loader=val_loader, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, criterion=criterion)
        recent_bleu4 = metrics["Bleu_4"]

        # Check if there was an improvement
        is_best = recent_bleu4 > best_bleu4
        best_bleu4 = max(recent_bleu4, best_bleu4)
        if not is_best:
            epochs_since_improvement += 1
            print("\nEpochs since last improvement: %d\n" % (epochs_since_improvement,))
        else:
            epochs_since_improvement = 0

        # Save checkpoint
        save_checkpoint(args.data_name, epoch, epochs_since_improvement, encoder, decoder, encoder_optimizer,
                        decoder_optimizer, metrics, is_best, final_args)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File D:\COCO\imge_captioning_transform_github\3\Image-Caption-master\train.py:394 in
train(args, train_loader=train_loader, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder, criterion=criterion,

File D:\COCO\imge_captioning_transform_github\3\Image-Caption-master\train.py:44 in train
for i, (imgs, caps, caplens) in enumerate(train_loader):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:368 in iter
return self._get_iterator()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:314 in _get_iterator
return _MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter(self)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:927 in init
w.start()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\process.py:121 in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\context.py:224 in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\context.py:327 in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py:93 in init
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py:60 in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\site-packages\h5py_hl\base.py:368 in getnewargs
raise TypeError("h5py objects cannot be pickled")

TypeError: h5py objects cannot be pickled
```

2022-06-30 17:24:41.206091: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations: AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-06-30 17:24:41.525476: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3497 MB memory: -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2022-06-30 17:24:44.486920: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:231] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:

```
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
args {
type_id: TFT_TENSOR
args {
type_id: TFT_LEGACY_VARIANT
}
}
}
is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
args {
type_id: TFT_TENSOR
args {
type_id: TFT_INT32
}
}
}

while inferring type of node 'cond_40/output/_25'
2022-06-30 17:24:45.077383: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1786] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Users\MSI\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
File "C:\Users\MSI\anaconda3\envs\my_envir_gpu\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I am using Python 3.9, PyTorch 1.10 with Cuda 11.3 (WINDOWS 10)

Thanks,

I am trying ( num_workers=0 ) , but still same error

Comment: The code is designed for Unix platforms where subprocesses can be started through forking without having to pickle objects that should be used by the subprocess. That doesn't work on Windows. If you don't have a Linux (or Mac) platform, try Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Comment: Or modify the code to open the HDF5 file *after* creating the subprocess

Answer (score 0):

This is linked with the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684061/typeerror-h5py-objects-cannot-be-pickled). However, the problem is due to Windows trying to pickle the `h5py` file when it tries to read the data using a number of subprocess's set using the `num_workers` parameter. A quick workaround is to set `num_workers==0` which then only reads from the main process. However, this will slow your training down.